# Show that a group that has only a finite number of subgroups must be a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Show that a group that has only a finite number of subgroups must be a finite group.

I started by assuming that group is infinite.

But, don't understand how I should go from this assumption

Comment: Start by proving that every element has finite order.

Answer (score 10):

Note that each $a\in G$ generates a subgroup $\langle a\rangle$. Noting that

$$G=\bigcup_{a\in G}\langle a\rangle$$

and any elements of infinite order produce a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$, so that this subgroup has infinitely many subgroups--i.e. if $\langle a\rangle$ is infinite, then $\langle a^n\rangle, n\in\Bbb N$ is an infinite family of subgroups (a contradiction). But then $G$ is a finite union of finite sets, making it a finite set itself.

Comment: Are you saying that every element in G is generating subgroup of G?

Comment: @nany yes, all elements generate subgroups

Comment: Sorry, but Could you explain why all elements generate subgroups..?

Comment: @nany by definition, just look at the set $\{a^n : n\in\Bbb Z\}$. This is a subgroup as $a^n*_Ga^m=a^{n+m}$ and $(a^n)^{-1}=a^{-n}$ and $a^0=e_G$.

Comment: @nany: For any group $G$ and any subset $S \subset G$, the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$, denoted $\langle S \rangle$, can be defined. One definition of $\langle S \rangle$ is the set of all products of finite sequences of elements of $S$ and their inverses. Another, equivalent definition is the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $\langle S \rangle$.

Comment: I think one needs to also account for the possibility that none of the elements has infinite order. I think it is not so obvious. So, one can then account for that possibility by saying that if each cyclic subgroup has finite order, and their union is supposed to be equal to an infinite set, there should be infinite number of such finite subgroups.

Comment: This is already in there, "if any" means if it has one which led to a contradiction, so the stuff that follows handles the (necessary) case where none exists

Comment: Oh okay, yes. I got thrown off a little. Thanks, anyway! @AdamHughes