# Conjugacy class with $1$ element in an Infinite Simple Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups, infinite-groups

> We would like to show that if $G$ is an infinite simple group, then
>   the only conjugacy class of exactly one element is $\{1_G\}$.

**My thoughts**: We want to proove that if $|\mathrm{orb}(x)|=1\iff \mathrm{orb}(x)=\{x\}$ then $x=1_G$.

We know that $|\mathrm{orb}(x)|=1\iff x\in Z(G)$. But, $Z(G)\trianglelefteq G$ and $G$ is simple, so $Z(G)$ is $G$ or $\{1_G\}$. Also, from the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem $|G|=|C_G(x)|=\infty$.

*But, I'm afraid these don't help as. Any ideas please?*

*Thank you.*

Comment: You're nearly there. If $Z(G) = G$, then $G$ is abelian. And simple. And infinite.

Comment: @Chris: If $G$ is infinite, then it has an infinite number of proper subgroups. If $G$ is abelian, then all of these subgroups are normal which is impossible because $G$ is simple. So, $Z(G)=\{1_G\}$.

Comment: @Tortoise Thank you for your comment. There another way to prove it avoiding the proper subgroups or possibly the result with the center?

Comment: @Chris: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322713/if-a-group-g-has-only-finitely-many-subgroups-then-show-that-g-is-a-finite or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132946/show-that-a-group-that-has-only-a-finite-number-of-subgroups-must-be-a-finite-gr

Comment: @Moritz Thank you for the useful link.

Comment: @Chris: If you follow the provided links above you should do fine. Good luck!

Comment: Slightly more involved exercise: in an infinite simple group, the only **finite** conjugacy class is $\{1\}$.